# What percentage of words or queries are misspelled in search queries?

Tags: reference-request, orthography, information-retrieval

What percentage of words or queries are misspelled in search queries?

I couldn't find any decently recent study. {3} states:

> Dalianis measured that 10% of web search engine queries were misspelled {1}. Wang et al. counted as misspellings 26% of the total of unique query terms {2}. We analyzed a random sample of 1 000 queries of the Portuguese Web Archive (PWA) and detected that 5% were misspelled.

but {3} was published 7 years ago, used as a small corpus, I would be interested in having results for English as well ({1} is on Swedish) and {1,2} were published almost 20 years ago.

{4} also used references that are ~20 year-old:

> A number of studies of search engine queries have observed a high misspelling rate (Nordlie 1999; Spink, Wolfram et al. 2001; Wang, Berry et al. 2003). Wang, et al. (2003) report a misspelling rate of 26% for words on an academic site.

Note that the percentage of words are misspelled in search queries is an lower bound of the percentage of misspelled search queries. I am more interested in the percentage of words are misspelled in search queries so that one doesn't have to consider the lengths of the search queries.

---

References:

- {1} Dalianis, H.: Evaluating a spelling support in a search engine. In: Andersson, B., Bergholtz, M., Johannesson, P. (eds.) NLDB 2002. Lecture notes in computer science (LNCS), vol. 2553, pp. 183–190. Springer, Heidelberg (2002) https://people.dsv.su.se/~hercules/papers/SpellingIR.pdf  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/save/https://people.dsv.su.se/~hercules/papers/SpellingIR.pdf))
- {2} P. Wang, M. Berry, and Y. Yang. Mining longitudinal Web queries: Trends and patterns. American Society for Information Science and Technology, 54(8):743–758, 2003. https://doi.org/10.1002/asi.10262
- {3} Costa, M., Miranda, J., Cruz, D. and Gomes, D., 2013, September. Query Suggestion for Web Archive Search. In iPRES. https://sobre.arquivo.pt/wp-content/uploads/query-suggestion-for-web-archive-search-1.pdf  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200409120412/https://sobre.arquivo.pt/wp-content/uploads/query-suggestion-for-web-archive-search-1.pdf))
- {4} Wilbur, W. John, Won Kim, and Natalie Xie. "Spelling correction in the PubMed search engine." Information retrieval 9, no. 5 (2006): 543-564.
  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2137159/ ; https://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2Fs10791-006-9002-8

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Quora](https://qr.ae/pNr1K4)
- [Reddit](https://redd.it/fxrato)

Comment: My bet is on an increase of misspellings: Since search engines generously correct wrong spellings no one cares to look twice on SE input.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica good point, true,  at the same time one could argue 1) increased use of speech recognition and swipe 2) better automated client-side spell checking 3) better typing ability.

Comment: I assume you mean universal misspellings and not dialect-relative misspellings. Colour is a mispelling in my dialect.

Comment: @user6726 yes, universal misspellings.

Comment: I bet on an increase too, because of the user expectation that it will be handled, and because of the shift to mobile and generally less literate users who may not be searching in their mother tongue.

Comment: It's useful to distinguish between 1) typos 2) misspellings due to ignorance 3) non-canonical forms due to lack of input method support for certain characters or diacritics 4) laziness/efficiency like lowercasing, omitting punctuation and certain abbreviations.

Comment: Without defining better what a misspelling is, the question is almost unanswerable.  It is relatively straightforward to use Google Trends to compare frequencies of different forms of a word.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer  agreed, defining better what a misspelling is welcome, e.g. see this study quoted in the answer I just posted.

Comment: The next problem is "random sample".  Like with word frequency counts, it's just not possible, there is no neutral corpus selection, there are just those that are aware that they're opinioned and those that aren't.  All of this will be a lot more answerable if there's a concrete application.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer agreed, just like in this studies quoted in the question, a study may focus on one domain of application. What do you mean by "there are just those that are aware that they're opinioned and those that aren't."?

Comment: I mean that many corpora are presented as if they are a random sample of the language.  Even when doing something as specific as compiling the queries of one search engine, there are a lot of arbitrary decisions.  With the search-as-you-type feature, it's not even clear if the user is finished, there are hardcoded millisecond cutoffs.  There are also bots doing queries.  A few outliers may skew results, but removing them is also subjective.  A lot of times they skew a corpus because they're repeated (eg Wikipedia footers), but if we dedup everything then we're skewing it another way.

Comment: So I'm uncomfortable with absolute answers to these types of questions like "42%" that aren't very explicit about these choices.  It's a bit easier if it's somehow relative.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer got it, thanks for the warning, I agree. Typically a decent paper woul clarify that, so I believe the question is answerable to a fair extent. This is research, not a school homework with one single clear and correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found this more recent paper: Duan, Huizhong, and Bo-June Hsu. "Online spelling correction for query completion." In Proceedings of the 20th international conference on World wide web, pp. 117-126. 2011. https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1963405.1963425:

> Our dataset for training the transformation model contains 1.4 million recourse link clicks. The statistics of the training data are shown in Table 2. Around 80% of all queries and 70% of all unique queries are correctly spelled. 1/10 of the training data is held out for parameter tuning.

It lists the following types of misspellings, which is quite keyboard-oriented:

[image]

which nicely complements https://www.dailywritingtips.com/7-types-of-misspellings/'s list:

> - Incorrectly repeated consonants
> - Wrong vowel
> - Wrong consonant
> - Reversed order of double vowels
> - Extra letters
> - Missing letters
> - Confusion with similar word

Comment: Can we just assume that *exxit* is a misspelling of *exit* or *silver light* of *silverlight*?  Both exist.  It's hard to know without analysing the session intent or asking the user.  And the other way around could happen too - a misspelling of the intended word that happens to be the correct spelling of another word.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer agreed, sometime classifying the misspelling isn't 100% clear without further analysis